# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Asp.Net Web Api Owin and Angular 8

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, cors, jwt, owin

I have a Asp.Net Web Api with JWT Oauth authentication mechanism. So in `Startup.cs` file I defined cors policy like this:

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

And I use validate ticket like this at `CustomOAuthProvider` class:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{

    var allowedOrigin = "*";

    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

    ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        return;
    }

    if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "User did not confirm email.");
        return;
    }


    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT");

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);

    context.Validated(ticket);

}
```

}

As you can see I defined for response headers in this:

```
var allowedOrigin = "*";

    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });
```

I couldnt set anywhere `EnableCors`, just in `StartUp.cs`.

But I am getting this error in client side(Angular 8):

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:50522/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am trying to use `login` method in angular like this:

```
login(username: string, password: string, grant_type: string) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.urlAddress}/oauth/token`, JSON.stringify({ username, password, grant_type }), { headers })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            console.log(user);
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            console.log(user);
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            return user;
        }))
}
```

I couldn't understand what is the problem exactly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved by removing `context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] {"*"});` code from  `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method.

And also I changed runtime order of `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` code before  `ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app)` code at `Startup.cs`